# Prove by Mathematical Induction $_ < 3,$ if $ _1 = 3,  ≥ 2,$ and $_{+1} = \sqrt {2(2 + _ )}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-explanation, induction

[induction example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl5e2.png)I am unsure how to solve this example as I do not know the value of n.
Could anyone help me with this question?

Comment: The phrasing is very odd.  What is $x$?  Do you mean that we can choose any $x≥2$?  But then why not just take $x=2$, since any other choice just strengthens the inequality?

Answer (score 2):

You have: $a_1 = 3 < 3x$ is true since $x > 1$. Assume $a_n < 3x$, then $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2(2+a_n)}< \sqrt{2(2+3x)}=\sqrt{4+6x}$. To complete the proof you need to verify that $\sqrt{4+6x} < 3x$. This is the same as $4+6x < 9x^2$. But $4+6x < 3x+6x = 9x < 9x^2$. Thus by induction, $a_n < 3x$ for all $n$.